# Get Routes Broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep getting the following error when upvoting or down voting my post:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/posts/181/up-vote"
```

Voter Partial:

```
<% if policy( Vote.new ).create? %>
      <div class="vote-arrows pull-left">
        <div>
          <%= link_to " ",
            post_up_vote_path(post),
            class: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up #{(current_user.voted(post) && current_user.voted(post).up_vote?) ? 'voted' : '' }", method: :post do %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <strong><%= post.points %></strong>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= link_to " ",
            post_down_vote_path(post),
            class: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down #{(current_user.voted(post) && current_user.voted(post).down_vote?) ? 'voted' : '' }", method: :post do %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Votes Controller:

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_post_and_vote

  def up_vote
    update_vote!(1)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def down_vote
    update_vote!(-1)
    redirect_to :back
  end
    private
    def load_post_and_vote
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @vote = @post.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first
    end

    def update_vote!(new_value)
      if @vote
        authorize @vote, :update?
        @vote.update_attributes(value: new_value)
      else
        @vote = current_user.votes.build(value: new_value, post: @post)
        authorize @vote, :create?
        @vote.save
      end
    end
  end
```

I have defined an up and down method within the votes controller. However, they are being called through a POST routes. Do I need to put it as :put or :down_vote???

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'comments/create'

  devise_for :users
    resources :users, only: [:update]

  resources :topics do
    resources :posts, except: [:index]
  end

  resources :posts, only: [] do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
      resources :favorites, only: [:create, :destroy]

    post '/up-vote' => 'votes#up_vote', as: :up_vote
    post '/down-vote' => 'votes#down_vote', as: :down_vote
  end

  get 'about' => 'welcome#about' # Redirecting the about variable to a welcome/about
  get 'newpost' => 'posts#new'
  root to: 'welcome#index'

end
```

Comment: You need to make sure the request method matches your route. If you defined the route to be a PUT then you need to make sure that your make a PUT request

Comment: When I rake routes, the routes are a POST request

Comment: can you add the routes.rb

Comment: Just added the routes.rb

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should not use GET to change the state of an entity, as that verb should leave it unchanged. POST is usually reserved to create entities (although it can be debatable).

PUT is the correct verb to update an entity.

Change your link to:

```
<%= link_to " ",
            post_up_vote_path(post),
            class: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up #{(current_user.voted(post) && current_user.voted(post).up_vote?) ? 'voted' : '' }",
            method: :put do %>
```

Then, in your `routes.rb` file, check that you have something like:

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    put 'up-vote'
  end
end
```

For more info, check the ever great guide at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

If still not working, check that a form with method PUT is created by ActionView, by inspecting the DOM with Chrome. See *method* here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to:

> This modifier will dynamically create an HTML form
>   ...
>   if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET

Check that:

- you don't have some JS code crashing
- JS is not disabled in your browser
- the page fully loaded before you try to click

Comment: ...and `jquery-ujs` is in place.